# Interface Builder Tips/Tricks Useful for a Beginner

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder

What are some useful tips/tricks for Interface Builder that would be relevant for a beginner?

Comment: Doing the layout in code may be easier in the long run if there are simple programmatic rules to follow (e.g. buttons with some strings a fixed width apart), and localizing nibs is more of a pain (merging changes when someone edits a nib? ARGH.)

Comment: You can use Tags to access the various UI elements. For example, add a tag of '13' to a UIImageView and then access that view via viewWithTag:13.

Comment: This should probably be a wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the greatest tip ever in all of iOS programming. It takes everyone bloody years to figure this out.

Open something in IB. Now click on say a view - that's a UIView - in your xib.

Now open up the inspector. If you do not know how to do that yet, use the "Help - Search' menu item and type in "Inspector".

So you are looking at the inspector, for your UIView.

the inspector has ***FOUR*** (count them) panels. Click on the RIGHT-MOST panel which has a ***little "i" symbol in a circle***.

NOW LOOK AT THIS - ***at the extreme top right it will show you the Class of the UIView***.  OK, so it just says "UIView".  So now you're saying to yourself, big deal.

But note, ***that is exactly where you CHANGE the class***. That's it!  The most important functionin all of human science and engineering! If YOU have made a new subclass of UIView (say "YourClassyView") ... ***THAT IS WHERE YOU CHANGE IT***!!!

Change the object in IB from being a normal boring UIView, to your YourClassyView, right there!

That's a big secret, hope it helps.