# Iphone - Drawing into a view : philosophy and interactions

Tags: iphone, graphics, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've understood that I need to subclass a UIView t be able to draw inside it.
The thing I don't understand yet, is the philosophy of the way i must be done...

Let's say I have a view controller, and depending on context, I may want to draw a line into one of the subviews it manages, or a circle, or a rect, or a processed graphic. Or lets say two points that are moving inside a view into a defined rect and that display a bigger point when they are close.

How may I subclass and define the subview to make it able to do this only into its drawRect method ?

How does the controller, **that manages more than this simple UIView** (let's imagine you have a view controller that manages a view inside which there are many other view, and you want to make some drawings in two of them), and that knows what is needed to be drawn into the correct view (it's a controller, isn't it ?), may interact with the views ? And when the drawing is done, how may the views interact with the controller ?

I've read many doc about drawings (apple, web, forums, tutorials, ...), but I still can't touch the philosophy of the way this must be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's very simple. Make a new class, OliverView, which is a UIView.  (ie, it is a subclass of UIView.) In that view, make it draw stuff in a fancy way, inside `drawRect`.

Now make a UIViewController, called OliverVC. In storyboard put an OliverView inside OliverVC. ([beginner explanation of how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262182/interface-builder-tips-tricks-useful-for-a-beginner/4268463#4268463)).

In the OliverView, have properties "hours", "minutes", "seconds".

Now, in OliverView  - in the drawRect - have a fancy way to *display* those values. (Pie chart, glowing letters, animation - whatever you want.)

Now, up in OliverVC, do some calculations to determine the time in Zimbabwe, for example.

Once you want a time displayed, ***simply set those properties in OliverView - - and you are done.***

Your colleague could be programming the OliverView. You need know nothing about how she is going to display the time.  Conversely, your colleague need know nothing about your calculations in OliverVC..

So, it's simpleL One part has the job of displaying the data.  One part has the job of coming up with the data (doing whatever sort of calculation is relevant in the app).

It's the only architecture possible in a "real time" screen device where the views can and do change at any time.

---

In answer to your question below: you've forgotten that quite simply, if you have a button that would be a whole separate element. (Perhaps sitting "on top of" the OliverView.) So, it's easy!

Comment: Very nice and helpful answer +1. I know that I had the problems myself when I started writing custom views. Once you get it it all makes sense.

Comment: Yes! Especially if the question is well-posed like this one.

Comment: well, but what about reverse interactions ? If my user touch some part in the custom view where the view knows that then a specific (and possibly global) action must be done. How does it tells the controller (that is supposed to control) to do the things that must be done ?

Answer (score 2):

The -drawRect method in your UIView subclass defines the onscreen appearance of the view. All drawing is done in -drawRect. Your UIViewController calls methods on its UIView to tell it to draw something differently or to perform some other action.

The UIViewController manages everything to do with the view that is not inherently associated with the drawing of the content. Data associated with the view is often stored in the controller.

Comment: @voidzm : Could you explain "Data associated with the view is often stored in the controller". How does the view may access datas that are into the controller, and how may it know what is to be used ?

Comment: Say for instance you are writing a view that displays a string. The string would usually be stored in the controller, and the controller would call [[self view] setStringToDraw:string]. You would need to have an instance variable and an mutator for the string defined on the UIView.

Comment: @voidzm : so what you are saying is that my UIView may store dozens of ivars just to use one of them when needed, that's it ?

Comment: More or less, yes. The controller just sets values into the UIView, and then the view uses then in the drawing.

Comment: @voidzm : "More or less"... More more, or more less ? :-)) That way of doing just seems incredible...

Comment: @voidzm : Isn't it at least possible to call something like `[theView drawMeThis:p1 p2:p2 p3:p3 ...]` and let it do without having to store anything nor calling drawRect ?

Comment: It would be quite possible to do that, but you would need to manually obtain the screen's graphics context beforehand. -drawRect automatically makes sure the current context is set to the screen, but you have no such guarantees in a custom method. Unless you really know what you are doing, it's best to just draw in -drawRect.